# How do I make my slider invisible if I have an AnimationRunning?

Tags: manipulate, animation

So this is something very similar to my code

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{Red, 
Rectangle[{0 + x, 0}, {2 + x, 0.5}],
PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {-1, 5}},
ImageSize -> Large],
{x, 1, 10, Appearance -> "Open", AnimationRunning -> True, 
AnimationRate -> v, 
AppearanceElements -> None},
ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

I'm trying to make the x slider invisible while the animation continues to run, but when I use

```
Invisible@{x, 1, 10, Appearance -> "Open", AnimationRunning -> True, 
  AnimationRate -> v, 
  AppearanceElements -> None}
```

the animation stops running. How can I make it so that while the slider is invisible, it continues to animate? should i use Animate instead of Manipulate?

Comment: `should i use Animate instead of Manipulate?` there is really no reason to use Animate over Manipulate. Manipulate can do what Animate does and much more. I always use Manipulate myself. Better learn one command well, than two not too well.

Comment: how will you stop/pause animation?

Comment: The animation shouldn't stop. it should keep looping

Comment: so does `v = 1; Animate[
 Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0 + x, 0}, {2 + x, 0.5}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {-1, 1}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], {{x, 1, Invisible[""]}, 1, 10, 
  AppearanceElements -> {}}, AnimationRunning -> True, 
 AnimationRate -> v, AppearanceElements -> None]` give what you need?

Comment: Yes, it does, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

#### Clock

```
Panel @ Graphics[{Red, 
   Rectangle[{0 + #, 0}, {2 + #, 0.5}] & @ Dynamic[Clock[{1, 10, .1}]]},
   PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {-1, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

#### Animate

```
v = 1; 
Animate[Framed @ Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0 + x, 0}, {2 + x, 0.5}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {-1, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> Large],
 {{x, 1, ""}, 1, 10, AppearanceElements -> {}}, AnimationRunning -> True, 
 AnimationRate -> v, AppearanceElements -> None, Paneled -> False]
```

[image]

#### Manipulate

**1.** Wrap the control with `Invisible @ Control`:

```
Manipulate[Framed @ Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0 + x, 0}, {2 + x, 0.5}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {-1, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> Large], 
 Invisible @ Control @ {x, 1, 10, Animator, AnimationRunning -> True, 
    AnimationRate -> v}, AppearanceElements -> None, Paneled -> False]
```

**2.** Use the `Method` option `"ControlAreaDisplayFunction"`:

```
Manipulate[Framed @ Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0 + x, 0}, {2 + x, 0.5}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {-1, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> Large], 
 {x, 1, 10, Animator, AnimationRunning -> True, AnimationRate -> v}, 
 AppearanceElements -> None, 
 Method -> {"ControlAreaDisplayFunction" -> (Invisible[#] &)}, 
 Paneled -> False]
```

Both methods give the same picture as the one produced by `Animate` above.